# Dovecot ignoring sieve

Tags: postfix, dovecot, sieve

I've a typical postfix+dovecot install in my email server. Works everything OK, with Roundcube as a webmail. The problem is that apparently the sieve plugin, which is activated, does not work or sth. because I've sieve rules which don't work. Here's a `.dovecot.sieve` from my user:

```
require ["fileinto","regex"];
# rule:[Spam]
if anyof (header :regex "from" ".*@163.com", header :contains "from" "shannuo061@yeah.net", header :regex "from" ".*@126.com")
{
        discard;
}
# rule:[Parabola-assist]
if allof (header :contains "to" "assist@lists.parabola.nu")
{
        fileinto "Maildir/.INBOX.Parabola-Assist";
        stop;
}
# rule:[Parabola-issues]
if allof (header :contains "from" "labs@parabola.nu")
{
        fileinto "Maildir/.INBOX.Parabola-Issues";
}
# rule:[Parabola-dev]
if allof (header :contains "to" "dev@lists.parabola.nu")
{
        fileinto "Maildir/.INBOX.Parabola-Dev";
}
# rule:[Test]
if allof (header :contains "from" "megver83@hyperbola.info")
{
        fileinto "Maildir/.INBOX.Parabola-Dev";
        stop;
}
```

In all the cases I've tried different directories, like omitting Maildir/, the .INBOX folder without the dot, etc, but same result. The worst is that there's nothing in the logs :S

This is my Dovecot configuration:

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
mail_plugins = " quota"
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  mailbox Drafts {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Spam {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    auto = subscribe
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix = 
}
passdb {
  args = /etc/passwd-file
  driver = passwd-file
}
plugin {
  quota = maildir:Cuota de usuario
  quota_warning = storage=95%% quota-warning 95 %u
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
}
protocols = imap pop3 sieve
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
  user = root
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 143
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
  }
}
service lmtp {
  user = vmail
}
service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
    port = 110
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
    port = 995
    ssl = yes
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_protocols = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 !SSLv3
userdb {
  args = /etc/passwd-file
  driver = passwd-file
}
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = " quota imap_quota imap_sieve"
  ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/server/fullchain.pem
  ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
}
protocol pop3 {
  ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/server/fullchain.pem
  ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
}
protocol sieve {
  ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/server/fullchain.pem
  ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
}
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = " quota sieve"
}
```

Comment: What version of dovecot are you running? (`dovecot --version`)

Comment: 2.2.29.1 (e0b76e3)